# Bubblesort to sort ascending order

Tags: data-structures, bubble-sort

Does anyone know any formula to find the total number of passes/number of swapping using Bubble sort
For e.g.

```
8,22,7,9,31,19,5,13
```

i have to sort in ascending order.I did it manually but want to know Formula in solving MCQs. Rather than manually,how can i use a formula to sort out it? A shortcut (if exists)?

Comment: There is no formula like maths for the same. Which language are you using? You could instead use libraries to sort them.

Comment: If i am given this in MCQ's ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11422184/4161269 you can read it .

Answer (score 1):

If the given data 8,22,7,9,31,19,5,13 is arrange in array

```
data[]={8,22,7,9,31,19,5,13}
```

And if 'total' is the total number of data in array. In this case

```
total=8
```

Below is the algorithm (formula) for bubble sort

```
 for(i=0;i<total;i++){
     for(j=i;j<total-1;j++)
      if(data[j]<data[i]){
       temp=data[j];
       data[j]=data[i];
       data[i]=temp;
      }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of swaps easily using the fact that it is equal to the number of inversions in the array(it is true because each swap in bubble sort decreases the number of inversions exactly by one).

Comment: I will use pencil & paper not IDE

Comment: @DavProgMania Counting the number of inversion manually is much easier than doing bubble sort step by step, anyway.

Comment: If u don't mind can u please demo.me working example using inversion of `8,22,7,9,31,19,5,13`