# number of swaps required in bubble sort without actually sorting it

Tags: c++, sorting, time-complexity, swap

I was just wandering if there is a way to actually find the number of swaps required by an array in bubble sort algorithm. I know some of you may think what is the harm in actually sorting the array using bubble sort and incrementing a count whenever we swap. But what i think is why to increase the complexity of a program unnecessarily as i only need the number of swaps that will be required to sort the array.
I need to decrease the complexity of below code.

```
void minimumBribes(vector<int> q) {
    int count=0;
    //returns Too chaotic if the element is farther then two positions to the left.
    for(int i=0;i<q.size();i++){
        if(q[i]-(i+1)>2){
            cout<<"Too chaotic"<<endl;
            return;
        }
    }
    //counts the number of swaps required
    for(int i=0;i<q.size();i++){
        for(int j=0;j<q.size()-i-1;j++){
            if(q[j]>q[j+1]){
                swap(q[j],q[j+1]);
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<count<<endl;

}
```

A small code snippet would be nice as i am not that good in this.

Comment: I can't see how you would do it. Each swap affects later comparisons, so you couldn't just do a "dry run" and come up with the right number of swaps.

Comment: Considering you only use bubble sorts for academical exercise I don't really see the argument in "reducing complexity"

Comment: Actually i need to decrease the complexity of a challenge and only way i see to do that is by doing this or do i post code and ask directly to decrease the complexity of code

Comment: there is no unnecessary increase in complexity. Counting the number of required swaps is of same complexity as actually doing the swaps. Maybe you misunderstand the meaning of "complexity" which isnt necessarily the same as efficiency

Comment: I don't think you could without sorting the list, but if you sorted it with something else (like qsort), you could brobably check how many positions each element needs to move and divide by 2 (since each swap moves 2 items 1 step each).

Comment: Or even better, copy the array which is O(n) and count the swap while doing the sort of your O(n^2) sort. The O(n) cost of the copy will be insignificant compared to the O(n^2) of the bubble sort itself

Answer (score 0):

To know the number of swaps should require only knowing the final positions of the sorted elements. The sorting itself can be done using a much better algorithm, so the overall cost will be that of the more efficient sort.

Comment: Could you demonstrate?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the point of the question is to determine the number of swaps a bubble sort algorithm would need to perform to sort the array. That would likely be a LOT more swaps than your suggestion would come up with.

Comment: @FredLarson I agree

Comment: I think this answer explains how to make use of the sorted vector to get the number of swaps bubble sort would need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11422184/487892

Comment: @drescherjm if anyone could please post a small code demonstrating that i think i would get it more easily.

Answer (score 0):

It's not feasible to calculate the number of swaps independently of actually performing those swaps.

There's several reasons that computational complexity is usually expressed in [Big-O Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), and one important reason is the fact that it's very difficult to make precise calculations ahead of time regarding how much work the sorting algorithm will need to perform.

Use the Big-O notation for your metrics regarding the speed of your sorting algorithm. If you want exact measurements, feed it some sample input that resembles the input you expect to see in your application, and track the quantity of swaps that are required to fully sort the input.

Answer (score 0):

As user463035818 has pointed out in the comments, counting the number of required swaps is the same complexity as actually doing the swaps i.e. you are trying to solve a problem that you don't have. If you are looking for efficiency, there is not much more you can do for a bubble sort. The only thing I can think of to further optimize is to add a flag indicating if a swap happened or not. If no swaps happened through a single pass of the inner loop, then the sorting is complete and you can exit your outer loop before reaching the end.  Note that if all the passes still need to be performed (worst case) then this solution performs slightly worse than your original one. However, for the best case of your vector already being sorted it should run at O(n).

```
int bubbleSortSwaps(std::vector<int> q)
{
    int count=0;
    for(size_t i=0; i<q.size(); i++)
    {
        bool swapped = false;
        for (size_t j=0; j<q.size()-i-1; j++)
        {
            if(q[j]>q[j+1])
            {
                swapped = true;
                std::swap(q[j],q[j+1]);
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (!swapped) // if no swap happened, it's sorted
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```