# I am counting bubble sort number of exchanges but time limit exceeds

Tags: c++, bubble-sort

I am solving a problem..
It's to count number of swaps in bubble sort.

Time limit- 1000  ms

n:number of  elements
datai = elements

Input

```
2 < n<=2000000

1<=datai<=n
```

sample input

```
5
3 3 2 2 1
```

sample output

```
8
```

this is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int s[2000005];

int main(){

    ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>s[i];
    }
    int ans=0;
    int flagg=0;
    int c;
    for(int k=0;k<n-1;k++){
        flagg=0;

        for(int i=0;i<n-1-k;i++){
            if(s[i]>s[i+1]){
                c=s[i];
                s[i]=s[i+1];
                s[i+1]=c;

                ans++;
                flagg=1;
            }

        }    
                if(flagg!=1)
            break;
    }

    cout<<ans<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But i always get time limit exceed

Do anyone knows how can i get faster?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find number of expected swaps in bubble sort in better than O(n^2) time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421170/how-to-find-number-of-expected-swaps-in-bubble-sort-in-better-than-on2-time)

Comment: Note, bubblesort is reasonable up to about 5000 elements, then it begins to diverge greatly from quicksort or mergesort. See [Time Comparison of Quick Sort, Insertion Sort and Bubble Sort](https://vinayakgarg.wordpress.com/2011/10/25/time-comparison-of-quick-sort-insertion-sort-and-bubble-sort/)

Comment: When you say always exceeds, do you mean even for small input?

Answer (score -2):

Your internal loop should look like this:

```
for(int k=0;k<n-1;k++){
    for(int i=k+1;i<n;i++){
        if(s[i]>s[k]){
            std::swap( s[i], s[k] );
            ans++;
        }
    }    
}
```

for the details, please check [How to find number of expected swaps in bubble sort in better than O(n^2) time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421170/how-to-find-number-of-expected-swaps-in-bubble-sort-in-better-than-on2-time)

Comment: Perhaps tell the OP *why* you think this is better? I'm personally curious to know why you believe a (your) head vs. (OP) tail target-bubble will perform any different, especially in your case *without* an early exit on already-sorted detection. Regardless, *neither* will perform well with a sequence of 200000 elements (that's over 20-billion iterations) *except* if swap detection terminates the sort very early due to already-sorted conclusion.

Comment: @Berto99 since when `#include <iostream>` and `using namespace std;` become C? Also, the tag `C++`... have you noticed that?

Comment: this is still  a selection sort, not a bubble sort

Comment: first line of the question `I am solve a probelm it's to counting how many swaps times in BUBBLE SORT.` --> your algorithm is a SELECTION SORT, and not even the best one from the moment that you are swapping a lot of numbers, instead of just finding the lower and swapping that, and also without any kind of early exit.